# "invalid date" error message when converting date format from csv file ? -shell

Tags: shell, csv, date, awk, date-arithmetic

I am new to shell scripting, I am trying to get the days of week from csv column that has dates in format :

```
16/10/2015
19/06/2010
16/09/2013
4/7/2008
29/12/2017
```

I used **date -%A** and got the results converted but not to all and still getting error message with results :

```
date: invalid date ‘16/10/2015’ 
date: invalid date ‘19/06/2010’ 
date: invalid date ‘16/09/2013’ 
Monday 
date: invalid date ‘29/12/2017’ 
Monday
```

Expected output:

```
Friday
Saturday
Monday
Wednesday
Friday
```

my code :

```
cat file.csv | awk -F "," 'NR>1 {print $4}' | awk -F, '{"date +%A -d\""$1 "\""| getline dte;$1=dte}1' OFS=","
```

I also tried to reformat the values into date type before converting  to make sure but still getting the error message, I have a big file of data that's why I am trying to loop on the whole column in awk

Comment: Could you please do add more details what you are trying to achieve by mentioning sample of expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: I updated my post with expected output

Comment: Convert `16/10/2015` first  to `2015/10/16`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert date fast to full name of the day of the week with GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {t=sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",$3,$2,$1); print strftime("%A",mktime(t))}' Input_file
```

---

See: [gawk - Date and time calculation functions](http://www.theunixschool.com/2013/01/gawk-date-and-time-calculation-functions.html)

Comment: This is much faster! and also for big data files which is what I needed, can you please explain this part `sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",$3,$2,$1)`

Comment: Field separator is `/`. If current row contains `16/10/2015` then `t=sprintf("%d %d %d 0 0 0",$3,$2,$1)` reformats this to a string `2015 10 16 0 0 0` and saves it to `t`. `t` now contains correct format for `mktime`. `sprintf` uses same syntax as `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following in pure bash(tested and written with provided samples only).

```
while read line
do
  IFS='/' read -ra arr <<< "$line"
  newDate=${arr[2]}/${arr[1]}/${arr[0]}
  date -d  $newDate +%A
done < "Input_file"
```

For provided samples following will be the output.

```
Friday
Saturday
Monday
Friday
Friday
```

Comment: Yes I did :) . just one small thing plz, will this way be good for big files? It takes longer time than in awk in my data file

Comment: @Mar, Honestly I didn't check with big data file but trust me this should be simplest one. Even you will put bash commands inside awk command could take time(can't say 100% but), you could check it once on same.

Comment: can I pipeline the results to use `sort | uniq` ? because only when I add pipeline it takes very long time

Comment: @Mar, `sort` or `uniq` but not sure why you need them? If you want to perform some further operation(which I am not sure at the moment  what you want to do) you could take output into a output file and then could perform operations on them?

Comment: With awk: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{print $3,$2,$1}' Input_file | xargs -n 1 date +%A -d`

Comment: it worked both ways also with awk, but the only problem that it takes long time when it's big file, I tried to pipeline the results to other file to do more operations but still taking long time.